# Implementing a publicly-editable tree where each node must hold private implementation data

Tags: object-oriented-design, access-control

I am trying to implement a tree data structure that callers of my code edit for me to operate on. The idea is that the caller can hold a reference to nodes from the tree and modify their data (both attributes and children), which triggers an event that prompts my code to update a visual render of the tree.

The problem that I have is that **each node also needs to hold some private data (a reference to the corresponding visual element) which I don't want to have polluting the public interface of the node object**. The private data needs to be accessible by the main class that is handling the tree object.

I *could* decide to just stick the private data onto my public interface like this:

```
class Node
{
    public int NodeData;
    public List<Node> ChildNodes;

    public object PrivateVisualizationData;
}

class TreeControl
{
    public Node RootNode;

    // Use "PrivateVisualizationData" fields on node objects
}
```

However, this presents two problems as I see it:

1. Any consumers of `Node` will see the `PrivateVisualizationData` field, which could be confusing
2. External code could modify my private data, breaking code that needs it

How could I design this structure so that each node has custom data associated with it, but the data isn't accessible externally? I would like to avoid the management cost of a separate lookup table if possible, but that may be what I end up doing.

Comment: So you need `PrivateVisualizationData` to be both accessible and not accessible?

Comment: the `internal` keyword comes to mind.  That, or accessing `protected` members from a base class.

Comment: Whan language is that? Java I presume.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20921365/equivalent-of-internal-in-java

Comment: What exactly do you consider "the management cost of a separate lookup table"?  Are you worried about performance or that development will be to hard to do?  If each node has an identity (some unique ID) looking up your private info would be trivial in a hashtable.

Comment: @TulainsCórdova @MetaFight `So you need PrivateVisualizationData to be both accessible and not accessible?` Yes. `Whan language is that? Java I presume.` It's C#, but it mostly doesn't make a difference. Marking the field as `internal` might work though.

Comment: @CandiedOrange Doing it with a lookup either means using the object itself or some basic attribute as a key in a hash table (which is slow when the table is large because it has to perform a search of the entire table) or using a unique ID as an array index (which  means that I must protect the unique ID from outside modification and make sure that every node has an incrementing ID). It's doable, but introduces its own problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try something like this:

```
    class Node
    {
        public int NodeData;
        public List<Node> ChildNodes;
    }

    class TreeControlNode extends Node
    {
        public object PrivateVisualizationData;
    }

    class TreeControl
    {
        private TreeControlNode RootNode;
        public Node GetRootNode()
        {
            return (Node)RootNode;
        }

        // Use "PrivateVisualizationData" fields on node objects
    }
```

Inheriting from the Node class allows you to use all of the members and methods of Node while still adding your special data. By returning your "RootNode" as the Node class the user should only us the Node members and methods.

Comment: OP will end up having the same problem. Any consumers of (now) `TreeControlNode` will see the `PrivateVisualizationData` field. Also *"The private data needs to be accessible by the main class that is handling the tree object."*.

Comment: That's true, but the point of `TreeControl` returning just a `Node` means that consumers using `Node` to modify the underlying tree maintained by `TreeControl` will only see `NodeData` and `ChildNodes` when working with the node.

Comment: I like this. The main issue that I have is that a caller could theoretically create a class implementing `Node` and add an instance of their class to my tree, and I would have no way of stopping it. I could probably just ignore nodes which aren't of the right type, but that introduces the possibility of silently failing because a caller didn't understand the API. Another option would be to create my own `Add`/`Remove` methods, but then I would be preventing use of the language's collection features.

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is probably to provide some additional metadata for the members that you do not want to display:

```
class Node
{
    public int NodeData;
    public List<Node> ChildNodes;

    [Hide]
    public object PrivateVisualizationData;
}
```

Your UI code can then check for the presence of the `[Hide]` attribute, and inhibit display.

If your UI is on the other object, then this is really no different from the usual separation of concerns that accompanies, say, an MVVM project.  Your class that represents the UI object is the ViewModel; you would simply copy those elements that apply from your domain object (TreeControl) into your ViewModel, and only those fields get displayed.

Comment: When OP says says he is worried that *"Any consumers of Node will see the PrivateVisualizationData field..."* I think he's thinking about client code, not necessarily final users through a UI.

Comment: Then he needs another collection that isn't exposed.  I assumed that, when he was talking about "visual elements," he was referring to UI.

Comment: Yes, this isn't exactly what I was looking for. Sorry if I wasn't clear; I updated the question to highlight the big point.

Comment: @WasabiFan: A member can't be public and private at the same time.  You'll either have to store the private data somewhere else, or use a boundary access modifier like `private` or `internal` to segregate your data.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Not necessarily. The goal is just to hide the "private" data from consumers; it isn't required to make it completely inaccessible to other code as long as it isn't easy to mess it up. So, for example, if my code only ever returned nodes by their `Node` interface type, the concrete class implementation pf `Node` could be the one that holds the private data while the consumer only sees the interface's fields. If I defined that concrete implementation within my manager class and made it `private`, the only way for a consumer to see the special data field would be through reflection.

Comment: Sounds like you've figured it out.